# Loading multiple assemblies in PowerShell with -AssemblyName

Tags: powershell

I want to load 4 Assemblies and currently I load them like this:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll';
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll';
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll';
Add-Type -path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll'
```

When I try to load them like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost, Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap
```

I get the following error:

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS' could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Microsoft.SqlS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS:String) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

If I only try to load one assembly:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS
```

Now there are two error messages:

```
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS' could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS:String) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. One or more required assemblies are missing.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_LOAD_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Comment: I think I need to use `Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly`

Comment: @mklement0: the paths in the C# project are the same as above (with the 4 `Add-Type -Path`). I don't understand... In C# I added them by finding them from the paths I have in PowerShell, e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll`

Comment: @mklement0: Then the only difference will be `LiteralPath` instead of `-Path`. But I already  have the full path (I guess that is the LiteralPath?).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you had included the `-Path` statements here. Since your full paths contain no wildcard characters, your `-Path` statements should act the same as `-LiteralPath`, but the latter is preferable for conceptual clarity. How did you find the full paths to begin with? Btw, please clarify if you are using Windows PowerShell or PowerShell (Core) 7+.

Comment: Also note that an `Add-Type -AssemblyName` command with multiple names aborts after the first failure, so it's possible that the remaining names too would cause failure.

Comment: @mklement0: I have been willing to ask another question about two different PowerShell terminals in my Visual Studio Code. I just turned of my computer, I will try to find out if I am using  PowerShell (Core) or Windows PowerShell tomorrow. To find the full paths I searched in the DAC folder using the search in file explorer.

Comment: Execute `$PSVersionTable.PSEdition` to determine what PowerShell edition you're running: `Core` implies the modern cross-platform, install-on-demand  [_PowerShell (Core)_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition, whereas  `Desktop` - or, in earlier versions, no output - implies the legacy, ships-with-Windows _Windows PowerShell_ edition.

Comment: @mklement0: `$PSVersionTable.PSEdition` returns Desktop.

Comment: @m: How can I load all assemblies whose name start with `Microsoft.SqlServer`?

Comment: @mklement0: I have added the errors when I try to only load one assembly.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243082/discussion-on-question-by-xhr489-powershell-not-guessing-net-type-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help.

```
If ($host.Name -eq 'ConsoleHost' -or
    $host.Name -eq 'Visual Studio Code Host') {

  try{  <#+------------------------------------------------+
          | Check that the proper assemblies are loaded    |
          | Required for PS Console and Visual Code, while |
          | only Systems.Windows.Forms needed for PSISE!   |
          +------------------------------------------------+
        #>
    $ATArgs = @{AssemblyName = "PresentationCore",
                               "PresentationFramework",
                               "WindowsBase"
                ErrorAction = 'Stop'}
    Add-Type @ATArgs
  } 
  catch {
   Write-Host $("Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework" +
        " and/or other assemblies required for this program!")
    Exit 
  }
  
} #End If ($host…
```

I include this code in all my scripts that use XAML based menus to insure that all necessary assemblies are loaded when I run in CLI Powershell, usually not necessary when using VSCode or PS-ISE.

Comment: Your solution is just a syntactic variation of what the OP - syntactically correctly, but unsuccessfully - tried (you're using splatting instead of direct argument-passing). The title of the question notwithstanding, the real question is why the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS` assembly, despite being present in a subfolder of the GAC, isn't being found by `-AssemblyName`.